# How to deploy contracts that take parameters in their initialisers using Truffle?

Tags: contract-development, truffle

I'm trying to build a smart contract with Truffle. I can compile it just fine, but when I try to deploy it on the network, I don't get an option to pass in the initialiser parameters and thus the contract fails.

How do I pass the parameters to a Truffle-compiled contract during deployment?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In your 2_deploy_contracts.js file you can add parameters when deploying the contract:

```
var Contract = artifacts.require("./Contract.sol");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(Contract,constructor_param_1, constructor_param_2, ,constructor_param_3, ,constructor_param_etc);

};
```

Comment: What if the contract argument is another contract? How is is provided in this deploy contracts file? For example I am trying to deploy this: https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/zeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/examples/SampleCrowdsale.sol
How do I provide `MintableToken _token`

Comment: How can you pass an argument to the utility which executes `2_deploy_contracts.js` (i.e., how can you pass an argument to `truffle migrate` or `truffle deploy`)?

Comment: Ha, found it. Just add it at the end of the `truffle migrate` command-line, and then in `2_deploy_contracts.js`, access it via `process.argv`.